# sharepoint onload set radio button value using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

Set choice field value using java script :

I have a choice field with values : 
Open
Closed
Cancelled

When my page loads, my choice column should be selected as "Cancelled"(i don't want to set using OOTB default value option.)

Comment: In which kind of Context, a Form ? Listview?

Comment: ootb list form say, editform.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the following radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="pink" /> Pink 
<input type="radio" name="color" value="black" /> Black
```

You can select the radio button using the following jQuery code. Insert this code in EditForm.aspx and you're good to go.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var presetValue = "black";
    $("[name=color]").filter("[value="+presetValue+"]").prop("checked",true);
});
</script>
```

Here is the JS only code:

Refer the JS in the EditForm.aspx:

Try this in your myjs.js file:

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("radio");
 var i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 var input = inputs[i];
 if (input.id.indexOf('color') > -1)     
    document.getElementById('pink').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('black').checked = true;
```

Comment: can i do it with javascript only.No jquery

Comment: What is the glitch while using jQuery?

Comment: for the particular requirement i can only use javascript.

Comment: try my updated response. Note, I haven't tested it myself so please feel free to improve it.